# The shelve module in Python2.7.5 create different database file

Tags: python, python-2.7, shelve

I want to create database by **shelve** module in **Python2.7.5** .
But, the shelve module create different database file on my two Environment.

#### case of MacBookAir

```
import shelve
shelve.open("todo") # -> create 'todo.db'
```

#### case of Windows7

```
import shelve
shelve.open("todo") # -> create 'todo'
```

MacBookAir and Windows7, Both are using the same Python2.7.5.
I've checked difference of shelve module source code, But I din't found any difference.

Why?

Comment: Could it be hiding the file extension on the windows computer?

Comment: @Zizouz212 in windows computer, file extension is not hiding. so created `todo` file don't have file extension.